# Международный и межкультурный: в чем различия?

Tags: лексика

Какова разница между словом "международный" и "межкультурный"? Речь о коммуникации. Могут ли эти слова использоваться как синонимы?

Comment: Мне кажется, что эти слова НЕ синонимы. Во-первых, нужен конкретный контекст, чтобы понять что конкретно они могут обозначать. Во-вторых, слова международный и межкультурный относятся к разным гнездам и смысл виден из корней. Одно относится к сфере отношений между народами, а второе - между представителями разных культур. Понятно, что описываемые словами явления отчасти пересекаются, отчасти нет. В третьих, многие словари слово "межкультурный" не регистрируют. И поэтому лучше его лишний раз не употреблять - отдает какой-то политикой и канцеляритом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это разные понятия.Коммуникация бывает международная и межкультурная.
Международный - 1. Связанный с отношениями между народами, странами. Синоним - мировой, всемирный, межнациональный, интернациональный; междунациональный, интернационалистский, транснациональный

Межкультурный – связанный с отношениями между различными культурами, т.е.  идеями, обычаями и искусством, которые распределены в определенном обществе (напр.: Он был пылким поклонником римской и греческой культуры..;.Великие культуры Японии и Китая.;Богатая история африканских цивилизаций и культур ). 
Синоним-межэтнический.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что разные культуры могут быть и в рамках одного народа. Взять, например, молодежные субкультуры. Грубо говоря, общение между русским готом и русским анимешником будет межкультурной (но не международной!) коммуникацией.

Comment: Нет, в данном случае вы не правы. Межкультурное общение - это общение между представителями разных наций, в том числе и в рамках одного государства, а международное - это общение разных государств, даже если они представляют собой один народ. Так общение Северной и Южной Кореи - международное, а русского и бурята - межкультурное.

Как одним словом назвать общение между представителями разных субкультур (готы, анимешники и пр.) я не знаю, да и вряд ли подобное слово существует вообще.

Comment: Почему же? Взаимодействие культур можно рассматривать на макро- и микроуровнях.
 http://www.grandars.ru/college/sociologiya/mezhkulturnaya-kommunikaciya.html   Американская культура, латиноамериканская, африканская, европейская, азиатская и т.д. -  макрокультуры. Внутри них субкультуры- общественные группы, характеризующиеся своими культурными особенностями (молодёжные, религиозные, социальные, национальные- диаспоры нацменьшинств внутри государства).